# Pyinstaller .exe not working in windows 10 and windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have an windows 7 32 bit virtual machine, on my Windows 10 64 bit machine in the virtual machine. I created the .exe file for the hello world program using pyinstaller, the exe runs fine in the windows 7 machine but when i tried it on the windows 10 and on my sister laptop windows 8.1 it just won't open. if i open the file through the cmd it just stuck on loading. 
Any idea what is going wrong there ?
thanx.

Comment: Same issue here. No luck yet

Comment: Hi Udi-Flp and lime,  did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with only windows 10 machines.
I build with command
`pyinstaller --onedir --noconsole --noupx Reserv.py`
but there was another dependency of **libiomp5md.dll** which was not included to my dist build directory. So when I add this file, my exe start to work with win10.